# Flex vs HTML/jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, flash, apache-flex

Many times I get quick page design inputs from business/clients which will be finally developed and integrated with application.
Before getting a sign off from them I let give them wire frames to get a feel of new UI.
My application UI is in Flex. But I find HTML/jQuery easy and quick to develop wire frames.
Is it a fair assumption that if I create a wire frame in HTML/jQuery then I will be able to recreate it in Flex too?

Comment: Yes, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a fair assumption. In general, Flash/Flex is more powerful than HTML/JS. Although with the advent of HTML5 and improvements in JavaScript libraries like JQuery, HTML/JS is getting closer to what you can achieve in Flex, the additional complexity  (supporting various browsers, graceful degradation, fake OOP, and a million flippin' DIVs), mean that any time you need to do something reasonably complex on the client, you can do it in a more manageable and extensible way in Flex.

A notable exception would be that you can't embed pages from other websites within a Flex web app (unlike HTML, and also unlike AIR).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is easy to protoype a website in jQuery. Especially if you use a framework like Knockout.js.

Knockout will allow you to quickly develop functional UI without having to write a ton of JavaScript.

http://knockoutjs.com/